# Central Admin > Web App > General Settings > Date/Time

Tags: 2013, date-time

SharePoint 2013 with Latest SP and CU: I have setup Central Standard time for a given web application. I uploaded a document and my local central time is `11:40am` but time stamp is `10:40am` that means SharePoint is not adjusting for daylight saving clock. What's the fix?

Comment: what is sharepoint version and patch level of farm?

Comment: SP 2013 with latest SP and CU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is workaround for this issue, which requir to change the config file on all server in farm.

Modify the `Timezone.xml` file to include the correct date and time for standard time and for daylight saving time. `Drive:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Config`

It is recommended that clear the config cache after that.

see the compelte details over here.
[Daylight saving time ended and Sharepoint still off by 1 hour](https://guidesharepoint.wordpress.com/2014/02/17/daylight-saving-time-ended-and-sharepoint-still-off-by-1-hour/)

Comment: That worked for me like a charm... I have changed by script all the sites and subsites and still it showed dates off by 1 hour. After changing the Timezone.XML and restarting IIS, it began to work correctly. Thanks